# How to make scikit learn Machine Learning model results reproducible

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-seed

I have trained a couple of models using `scikit-learn` toolkit and when I run the models on different machines it is giving different results but when I run the same model any number of times on the same machine the results are the same, How to fix this?

sample code :

```
model = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(
        n_estimators=1000, 
        max_depth=3,
        min_samples_split=2, 
        max_features=n,
    )

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have been using joblib.dump(model,file) to dump and joblib.load() to load for prediction

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I cannot share the entire code but if you need something specific I would be glad to share

Comment: Externally iam not using anywhere but not sure whether some models are using them internally

Comment: What do you mean something specific? I'm not a magician and I cannot guess what mistake you've done.

Comment: I have trained these models SVM, RandomForest, KNN using scikitlearn

Comment: Are you using `train_test_split`?

Comment: Yeah iam using that

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to use a seed in order to get reproducible results. It would be something like this: https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-set-the-global-random_state-in-scikit-learn/

Comment: Are you sure setting the NumPy random seed will help with the replicating the same results even when the machine is changed?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal of setting a seed. Check here for more details: https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-random-seed/

Answer (score 2):

The random seed is a number  used to initialize a pseudo-random number generator. If you don't use a fixed seed, then the pseudo-random numbers generated will always be different as the number used to initialize the generator will be different.

---

Now if you want your results to be reproducible, you must use a fixed seed in case you are using  `scikit-learn` functions that take as an argument a random seed, you must make sure that the seed is always the same. For example, for `train_test_split` you must also use a hardcoded `random_state`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

If you don't do that, then in every run you will end up having different training and testing sets and therefore your results will vary.

The same applies for some particular `scikit-learn` models that accept a `random_state` parameter. If you are using any of them, make sure that you use a fixed `random_state`.

---

Also, if your code calls `random()`, you also need to make sure that you use a fixed seed:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
```

As a side note on `np.random.seed()` in general, if you want to call `np.random.permutation(10)` multiple times and get identical results, you also need to call `np.random.seed(42)` every time you call `permutation()`.

For instance,

```
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
print(np.random.permutation(10))
```

will produce different results:

```
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
[0 1 8 5 3 4 7 9 6 2]
```

while

```
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
```

will give the same output:

```
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
np.random.RandomState(seed=42).permutation(10)
```

which does not have a localised effect.

Comment: Will try this out, iam having a problem only when I do the prediction on different machines with the same model trained once, So should I consider retrain the models using `np.random.seed`?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu Not just `np.random.seed`. This is optional in case you are not using any functions from `random`. But in case you are using `train_test_split` you __must__ provide `random_state` in order to get reproducible results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try :)

Comment: @SundeepPidugu If you haven't provided `random_state` then this is 100% your problem here.

Comment: But my problem is in the predictions from the model changing every time when running on different machines with the same code and models.I get the same exact result when I run the code on the same machine any number of times. Not sure what has that do with the `train_test_split`

Comment: @SundeepPidugu You need to study how Machine Learning models work then. Obviously, if you are using different training data, the learned parameters will vary and thus the predictions over your test data will be different as well.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are getting different predictions on different machines with same code.

Try to train the model on a machine and save the trained model. You can use `pickle` module for that. Here is the sample code for saving and restoring a trained model.

```
import pickle


# Code for your model goes here
# model = ...

# Saving the trained model in the current working directory
pkl_filename = "pickle_model.pkl"
with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)

# Load trained model from file
with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:
    pickle_model = pickle.load(file)

# Use the loaded model to predict values
y_pred = pickle_model.predict(X_test)
```

You can copy the pickle file to any machines and it would make sure that same model gets loaded every time.

Moreover, if you want to train the model on different machines and get same results, you would want to use a fixed seed for all pseudo random generators.

Comment: Iam exactly doing this to save my `.pkl` files and loading them back to predict. Can you please elaborate more about the last paragraph on the fixed seed?

Comment: Have a fixed seed for all the pseudo random generators. For example: fix a seed using `np.random.seed`, setting `random_state` in  'train_test_split'. Some models such as random forest are naturally dependent on randomness. Then in that case, you would have to set the `random_state` for your `RandomForestRegressor` as well. Make sure you are setting it. Depending on all the functions you are using while training, you would want to set random_state for all of such functions.

Comment: I have been using `joblib.dump(model,file)` to dump and `joblib.load()` to load for prediction

Comment: Are you setting the `np.random.seed`, `random_state` for `train_test_split` and `random_state` for your `RandomForestRegressor`?